# Actualización de campo mediante un archivo excel.CSV

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, php5

Realizo un modulo en el cual es una actualización de datos pero es **masiva** **por medio de un excel.CSV,** tengo los siguientes campos en mi tabla "trabajador", algunos son llaves foráneas de otras tabla:

```
id_Control Primaria  
nombre  
ap_paterno  
ap_materno      
NSS 
CURP    
RFC     
fecha_nac   
id_puesto FK    
id_area FK  
idctg_turno FK  
idctg_empresa FK  
id_nomina FK
```

Lo que pretendo es que **solo se actualicen únicamente los datos del campo de idctg_turno** **conforme al id_Control y los otros datos queden intactos**. Anexo mi código de actualización masiva, el problema que tengo no se si es correcto el modo que lo estoy realizando ya que no actualiza ningún datos. Gracias.

Al tratar de importar mis archivo excel.csv me marca el siguiente error

`Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplo_excel.php on line 36` en muchas lineas

```html
<form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <p><label>Seleccione un archivo(solo formato CSV)</label>
    <input type="file" name="product_file" /></p>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-info" value="Upload" />
   </form>
<?php

    
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","BD");

if($connect){
  //echo "se realizo correctamente la conexion";
}else{
 //echo " no se realizo correctamente la conexion";
}
 
  
  
  


   if(isset($_POST["upload"]))
{
 if($_FILES['product_file']['name'])
 {
      $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['product_file']['name']);
      if(end($filename) == "csv")
      {

       $handle = fopen($_FILES['product_file']['tmp_name'], "r");
       //recorriendo el archivo
       while($data = fgetcsv($handle))
       {
        $id_Control = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[0]);
        $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[1]);  
        $ap_paterno = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[2]);
        $ap_materno = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[3]);
  $NSS = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[4]);
  $CURP = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[5]);
  $RFC = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[6]);
  $fecha_nac = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[7]);
  $id_puesto = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[8]);
  $id_area = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[9]);
  $idctg_turno = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[10]);
  $idctg_empresa = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[11]);
  $id_nomina = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[12]);
  
        $query = "
         UPDATE trabajador 
         SET idctg_turno = '$idctg_turno', 
   nombre = '$nombre',
   ap_materno = '$ap_materno',
   ap_paterno = '$ap_peterno', 
   NSS = '$NSS',
   CURP = '$CURP',
   RFC = '$RFC',
   fecha_nac = '$fecha_nac',
   id_puesto = '$id_puesto',
   id_area = '$id_area',
   idctg_turno = '$idctg_turno',
   idctg_empresa = '$idctg_empresa',
   id_nomina = '$id_nomina',
         WHERE id_Control = '$id_Control'
        ";
        mysqli_query($connect, $query);
       }
       fclose($handle);
       echo "actualizacion exitosa !! ";
      }
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error lo que está diciendo es que `$data[1]` no tiene ningun valor.
Para depurar un poquito lo que intentas hacer te recomendaría utilizar `print_r ($data)` dentro del while para ver que indices tiene tu variable data.

También destacar que en el manual de php hay un ejemplo muy fácil, que podrías utilizar, está en este enlace http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php.

Y ya por último en un vistazo rápido he visto que compruebas si se ha hecho la conexión pero no escribes la lógica de tu script dentro del bloque que confirma que dicha conexión está hecha, esa parte la podrías mejorar.